# ExtJs: Search / Filter within a ComboBox

Tags: extjs, combobox, filter

I've the following problem / question in ExtJs 2.3:

I'd like to do a search within a combobox.
I'll give you an example:

```
Ext.comboData.names = [['Peter', 'Paul', 'Amanda']];

var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
     fields: ['name'],
     data: Ext.comboData.names
});


var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
     name: '...',
     id: '...',
     store: store,
     displayField: 'name',
     typeAhead: true,
     mode: 'local',
     forceSelection: false,
     triggerAction: 'all',
     emptyText: '-',
     selectOnFocus: true,
     applyTo: '...',
     hiddenName: '...', 
     valueField: 'name'
     enableKeyEvents: true,
     lastQuery: '',
     listeners: {
         'keyup': function() {
               this.store.filter('name', this.getRawValue(), true, false);
         }
     }
});
```

When I would type in an 'a', there only should be 'Paul' and 'Amanda' in the "dropdown". So in other words I'm looking for a solution to filter the data not only by the entries' first letter, but maybe by using something like a regular expression (?) (like in SQL ... LIKE '%a%')...I also would need type of "onKeyDown"-event for my comboBox in order to filter the results on every single letter I add.
How can I do that? Any ideas?

Tanks a lot in advance :)

Schildi

PS: Unfortunately I have to use my current version of ExtJs (2.3), so if there's a solution for my problem just in later versions, I would have to look for an other way...

Answer (score 10):

`anyMatch: true` is all you need. (like in SQL ... LIKE '%a%') as you asked can be done by simply add this.

**Example:**

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
  name: 'name',
  anyMatch: true,
  allowBlank: true,
  editable : true,
  typeAhead: true,
  transform: 'stateSelect',
  forceSelection: true,
  queryMode: 'local',
  displayField: 'name',
  valueField: 'id',
  selectOnFocus: true,
  triggerAction: 'all',
  store: {
    fields: ['id', 'name'],
    proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: '/user'
    },
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true
  }
})
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer since v4.2.1!
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox

Comment: anyMatch: true and queryMode: 'local' both are required to achieve the functionality as you shown in example.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but the best answers here recommend overriding `doQuery`. Overriding private methods should be avoided especially if you are ever going to upgrade.  Instead, just add a `beforequery` listener to prevent `doQuery` from clearing the filter.

```
listeners: {
     'keyup': function() {
           this.store.filter('name', this.getRawValue(), true, false);
     },
     'beforequery': function(queryEvent) {
           queryEvent.combo.onLoad();
           // prevent doQuery from firing and clearing out my filter.
           return false; 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Very succinct solution.
But I had to add queryEvent.combo.expand() in 'beforequery' listener to make it work properly.

Comment: When using this piece of code I end up losing the ability of navigating the combobox using the arrow keys once I start typing for a search.

Answer (score 2):

[ExtJS ComboBox](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-2.3.0/docs/?class=Ext.form.ComboBox) has a `keydown` event (and `keyup`, and `keypress`) that you can use for this purpose.

[ExtJS SimpleStore](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-2.3.0/docs/?class=Ext.data.SimpleStore) also has a `filter` method that should suit your purpose. You can use it like this (to find values that contain an 'a' character):

```
store.filter('name', 'a', true, true)
```

First parameter is the record field, second is the string/regexpt to look for, third parameter means that filter should match any part of field (instead of just the beginning of the value), and the last value determines the case-sensitivity. You can turn it off, of course, if you like.

All of this applies to ExtJS 2.3.0. Hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your answer! :) I no added a listener to my comboBox (see above), but my problem is, that the store still isn't filtered when I type some letters :( is there still anything wrong with my code?

Comment: I am not sure if `getRawValue()` is the correct way to get the user input during the event. I suggest that you debug the event with Firebug (set up a breakpoint), to see what value you're passing into the filter. Also examine the `EventObject e` that is passed in as a parameter.

Comment: I agree with Tommi. Firebug rules. That's my M.O. when I start looking into the issues.  For fun, try passing along a few extra parameters in your event and see what you have access to as well. Sometimes there are golden nuggets that you can find.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by overriding the doQuery method of combobox.

Answer (score 1):

just remove that lister and override the doQuery method as follows

```
if(combo!=null){
    combo.doQuery = function(q, forceAll){
  q = Ext.isEmpty(q) ? '' : q;
  var qe = {
      query: q,
      forceAll: forceAll,
      combo: this,
      cancel:false
  };
  if(this.fireEvent('beforequery', qe)===false || qe.cancel){
      return false;
  }
  q = qe.query;
  forceAll = qe.forceAll;
  if(forceAll === true || (q.length >= this.minChars)){
      if(this.lastQuery !== q){
          this.lastQuery = q;
          if(this.mode == 'local'){
              this.selectedIndex = -1;
              if(forceAll){
                  this.store.clearFilter();
              }else{
                  this.store.filter(this.displayField, q, true,false); // supply the anyMatch option
                  }
                  this.onLoad();
              }else{
                  this.store.baseParams[this.queryParam] = q;
                  this.store.load({
                      params: this.getParams(q)
                  });
                  this.expand();
              }
          }else{
              this.selectedIndex = -1;
              this.onLoad();
          }
      }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement in ExtJs4
Check the tweaks in the below link... It worked for me perfectly.

http://atechiediary.blogspot.in/2013/06/first-page-extjs-containslike-search-in.html

Answer (score 0):

I cam across something similar before. I looked into the [doQeury function](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/Combo.html#method-Ext.form.ComboBox-doQuery) and it would seem to be filtering using the display name, without having set [anyMatch](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store) parameter in the filter function. In such cases, there are no easy solution but to override doQuery or a  create a new user extension. Fortunately, one can be found [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?53232-Combobox-remove-space-during-search&p=253617#post253617)

I think this may apply to Ext 2.3 since we recently upgraded, I would seem to have lost my documentation links. But that is how I would go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach also:
provide a listener to combobox and catch this event:

```
 change: function() {
                        //debugger
                        var store = this.getStore();
                        store.clearFilter();
                        store.filter({
                            property: 'deviceName',//your property
                            anyMatch: true,
                            value   : this.getValue()
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the keyup event. I did not get it working with this.getValue(). had to use this.getRawValue()

```
keyup: {fn:function() {
                        var store1 = ContractStore;//store object
                        store1.clearFilter();
                        store1.filter({
                        property: 'modificationnumber',//your displayField
                        anyMatch: true,
                        value   : this.getRawValue(),
                        exactMatch: false,
                        caseSensitive: false
                    });
```