# ComboBox with anyMatch search in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4

I have a ComboBox with a remote store with local filtering.
Instead of the default filtering, by the first characters like `%query`, I want to filter with the contains/anyMatch mode like `%query%`.

I tried to solve this with the answers in the question: [ExtJs: Search / Filter within a ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5511223/2139775), but it didn't worked.

**Code:**

```
var users = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox',{
    displayField : 'userName',
    valueField : 'userName',
    queryMode : 'local',
    typeAhead : true,
    store : Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model   : 'User',
        proxy       : {
            type    : 'ajax',
            url     : './user/list',
            reader  : {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just have to add the following code in the `Ext.form.field.Combobox`. This works in ExtJs 4.1 that doesn't have the `anyMatch` property.

```
listeners   : {
    beforequery: function(record){  
        record.query = new RegExp(record.query, 'i');
        record.forceAll = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [anyMatch](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-anyMatch) config option since Ext 4.2.1. In earlier versions it looks like you'll need to override `doQuery` method in `Ext.form.field.ComboBox` just to be able to add that option to the filter instance you'll find in there:

```
me.activeFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
    root: 'data',
    anyMatch: true, // <- add this
    property: me.displayField,
    value: queryString
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The modifier `g` is more important, for a global search. `i` is only for case insensitive search.

```
listeners   : {
beforequery: function(record){  
    record.query = new RegExp(record.query, 'ig');
}}
```

Comment: Using Ext JS 3.4.1, this example of overriding the beforequery event handler does change `queryEvent.query` from a string to a RegExp object.  But, then none of the combobox's items match that query, even if I type characters that I know some of the items contain.  Also, if I type a parenthesis, I get a crash because that parenthesis is treated an invalid part of the regular expression.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919737 expands on this example, and solves both of my problems.   Using `Ext.escapeRe()` avoids crash when the search string contains regular expression symbols.  Adding the `length` property to the created `RegExp` object is apparently a trick so that `doQuery` can compare that length to minChars