# ExtJs 3.4 combobox autocomplete interchangeably of character position

Tags: extjs

I am using extJs 3.4 combobox autocomplete, i want autocomplete search to work interchangeably of characters position.
For example when i type 'v' it autocompletes to vanessa (it is working well) but when i type 'a' it doesnt autocomplete.
i would like to autocomplete by any character(that exist) in any site.
Something like this 
a - vanessa,daniela
s - vanessa
or ssa - vanessa

This is my code

```
xtype: 'combo', 
fieldLabel: 'prov',
id : 'lang', 
store:[['tr','vanessa'],['ru','daniela'],['en','English']],
mode: 'local', 
triggerAction: 'all',
selectOnFocus:true,
listeners: {
afterrender: function(combo) {
    var recordSelected = combo.getStore().getAt(1);                     
    combo.setValue(recordSelected.get('field1'));
}
```

}

Thank you and i apologize for my grammar it isn't very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to somewhat change the behaviour of the [`doQuery`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/source/Combo.html#Ext-form-ComboBox-method-doQuery) method. As you see in the code, we're lucky because there's an event giving us the opportunity to do that without hacking the combo too much :) Furthermore, if we pass a regex to the store's [`filter`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter) method, it will ignore its other arguments (the one we would have wanted to pass is `anyMatch`... but the combo doesn't give us the opportunity).

So, we just have to hook on this event and transform the `query` string property into a regex! Here's how:

```
Ext.create({
    xtype: 'combo',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    fieldLabel: 'prov',
    id: 'lang',
    store: [
        ['tr', 'vanessa'],
        ['ru', 'daniela'],
        ['en', 'English']
    ],
    mode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    listeners: {
        beforequery: function(q) {
            // we don't want to crash if there's nothing in there
            if (q.query) {
                // we need the length later in the doQuery function,
                // for respecting minChars
                var length = q.query.length;
                q.query = new RegExp(Ext.escapeRe(q.query));
                // pretend I am a string, eh eh
                q.query.length = length;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You may want to override the `Ext.form.ComboBox` class to add this as an option (I would call it `anyMatch`) since that's a pretty common requirement.

Comment: wow dude thank you that was pretty fast and it works perfect.

Comment: This example worked for me using Ext JS 3.4.1.  My only addition was to create the `RegExp` object with the `i` flag for case insensitive search.  e.g.:  `q.query = new RegExp( Ext.escapeRe( q.query ), 'i' );`