# ExtJS - After clearing filter(s) of store, type query does not work

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I'm using instances of a `combobox` for multiple user interfaces. So I need to reset combobox stores when user focuses on it. Combo's store is **locally sorted**; so I execute `clearFilter()` function of `Ext.data.Store` class - it works as it is expected except that **typing query** does not work anymore.

Here is my **combobox** configuration:

```
forceSelection: true,
autoSelect: false,
typeAhead: false,
triggerAction: 'all'
```

**Store** configuration:

```
autoLoad: false,
autoSync: false,
remoteSort: false,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax'
    // other configs
}
```

**Edit:** [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/te2)

**Note:** `Store` of `combobox` used in fiddle is populated with **static data** when the original one uses an `AJAX proxy`

Comment: please provide a fiddle showing your problem

Comment: I have edited the original post & added the fiddle link. But please keep in your mind - as I commented in the fiddle - `store` of combobox used in fiddle is populated with static data when the original one uses an `AJAX proxy`. There are no issues in the fiddle; difference of store population may be the reason behind it. @LucianDepold

Comment: Why do you need to run clearFilter() ? If you remove the clearFilter line the autocomplete works when switching between panels.

Comment: autocomplete is not the problem here; the populated data is filtered through the query entered on other combobox @LucianDepold

Comment: By autocomplete i ment the type query. In your fiddle you use two stores, one for each combo. So deleting clearFilter() seems to solve the problem. Should there be only one store for both combos ?

Comment: yes, since they are just instances - both their data & business rules are same. As I said there are no issues in the fiddle since it uses static data with a local query mode. The original one uses AJAX proxy to load the data remotely. But it is not in need of query remotely. This is also necessary to improve the performance - local query is enough. @LucianDepold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i solved your problem by looking at this post:
[ExtJs: Search / Filter within a ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511223/extjs-search-filter-within-a-combobox)

Adding a custom filter on each keystroke on the combobox seems to resolve your issue:

```
    enableKeyEvents:true,
    listeners: {
     'keyup': function() {
           this.getStore().clearFilter();
           this.getStore().filter('name', this.getRawValue(), true, false);
     },
     'beforequery': function(queryEvent) {
           queryEvent.combo.onLoad();
     }
 }
```

It is not beautiful, but i think it works. Take a look at this extended fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/teg

Comment: as you said Lucian, it is not the best way to solve this issue - especially for the best performance; still your solution can be used for a quick fix. According to docs, if the store is populated remotely, combo must be configured in `queryMode: remote` after store is configured with remote sort (`remoteSort: true`). I think my case should be provided in order to improve query performance.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your fiddle, you have trouble that implementing filter to different comboboxes. I think the problem you currently use same store for comboboxes. That's why you should also change the store for each combobox. Add this code to your fiddle.

```
combo1.getStore().filter('nationality', 'USA');

        container.on('tabchange', function(tabpanel, newCard, oldCard, eOpts) {
            combo2.getStore().clearFilter();
            combo1.getStore().filter('nationality', 'USA');
            if (combo2.getValue()) {
                combo1.getStore().clearFilter();
                combo1.getStore().filter('userId', combo2.getValue())
            }
        });
```

Btw, I put the filter before tabchange event because of static store. But, you might want to add the filter store listener if you use proxy(AJAX) store. Like this:

```
listeners: {
  load: function(store, records) {
      store.filter('nationality', 'USA');
  }
}
```

Edit:

```
 var store = combo1.getStore();
 store.filter('nationality', 'USA');

            container.on('tabchange', function(tabpanel, newCard, oldCard, eOpts) {
             if (newCard.title == 'Panel 1') {
                store.clearFilter();
                store.filter('nationality', 'USA');
             } else if (newCard.title == 'Panel 2') {
                store.clearFilter(); 
                // Or whatever filter because you have to change the store                         
                // dynamically if you wanna use same store for different combos
             }
        });
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: actually it does not make sense to create a new store per each instance of a combobox - their data is same; they just belong to different user interfaces. In your code, you filter each combo through the other one's value which is not necessary.

Comment: I agree creating a new store does not make sense. If you could check my code, you would notice that I used same store for comboboxes. Besides, that code was an example to show to how to change the store dynamically. Anyway, I will edit my code to make more simple.

Comment: the problem here is the populated data which is filtered that is affected by other combo. When I clear filters as you do, key listeners do not work anymore. According to docs, if the store is populated remotely, combo must be configured in `queryMode: remote` after store is configured with remote sort (`remoteSort: true`) which lacks performance for the case if the whole data is already fetched.

Comment: Now, your problem is clear. I have never faced that kind of issue so far. Key listeners are supposed to work. Maybe, you should upgrade your sencha. As for  remote store, it doesn't have to be configured in queryMode: remote. If store is already fetched, you can use that store without fetching again. Let me create a fiddle.

Comment: As I thought, I have never faced the problem, which key listeners don't work when I run clearFilters(). Also, you can check that the store would be fetched one time(I put the console.log to store's listener) Here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tel